# Finding distribution for a pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions, density-function

We are considering the equation of pendulum
$$
x''+x=0,
$$
with the initial conditions $x(0)=A \sin \varphi$, $x'(0)=A \cos \varphi$ ($A$ is an amplitude, $\varphi$-intitial phase). How to determine distribution of probability for coordinate $x(t)\in[-A,A]$ for $t>0$ knowing that initial phase $\varphi$ has uniform distribution on interval $(-\pi,\pi)$? For which $x \in [-A,A]$ this density (for obtained distribution) is little and for which big?

Any advices will be strongly desirable, because I'm weak in physics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be shown quite easily that at any $t>0$ we have  $X=A\sin(\varphi+t)$. Now suppose $\Theta \sim \mathcal{U}(0,2\pi)$ and fix $x\in[-A,A]$. It follows that $$F_{X}(x)=\mathbb{P}(A\sin(\varphi+t)\leq x)=\mathbb{P}\Big(\sin(\Theta) \leq \frac{x}{A}\Big)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arcsin\Big(\frac{x}{A}\Big)$$ Therefore for $x\in(-A,A)$ $$f_{X}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\Big[F_X(x)\Big]=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{A^2-x^2}}$$
This is the formulated density on $(-A,A)$. The density vanishes elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I have two questions: why $\theta$ has uniform distibution on the interval from $0$ to $2\pi$, not from $-\pi$ to $\pi$? The second question: should it not be $\frac{1}{2\pi}\arcsin (\frac{x}{A})$ at the end of first line with evaluations?

Comment: First of all, notice if $\varphi \sim \mathcal{U}(-\pi,\pi)$ then $\varphi + t \sim \mathcal{U}(t-\pi,t+\pi)$ for fixed $t$. Moreover, if $\Theta_1\sim\mathcal{U}(0,2\pi)$ and $\Theta_2\sim\mathcal{U}(a,a+2\pi)$ for fixed $a\in\mathbb{R}$, try to convince yourself that $$\mathbb{P}\Big(\sin(\Theta_1)\leq x/A\Big)=\mathbb{P}\Big(\sin(\Theta_2)\leq x/A\Big)$$ In order to evaluate $\mathbb{P}\Big(\sin(\Theta_1)\leq x/A\Big)$ you need to find the measure of the red arc in this graph and divide this measure by $2\pi$ radians:  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lvrwihztsu

Answer (score 0):

The density of $x$ is inversely proportional to the velocity there because when it is moving fast it gets away from a given point quickly.  The velocity is proportional to the square root of the kinetic energy at a point.